# Is there any sort of theme dependency management?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, wp-dependencies

I'm developing a Wordpress theme with a few other individuals and am running into a problem where I add a plugin and then I have tell the other developers about the plugin I installed and the settings I set for the plugin so that the theme works.

I was wondering if there's a way to associate plugins with a theme, so that when an individual receives the theme, the theme knows which plugins it needs and can automagically install them and their correct versions.

I suppose I'm looking for some sort of dependency management for Wordpress themes. Is there something like that out there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't any such feature directly in wordpress but there is a php library that do allow this kind of behaviour. Can't comment on how/if it works as I haven't tried it yet but it looks like it does the job.

You might find it useful http://tgmpluginactivation.com/

Answer (score 0):

In addition with Mridul Aggarwal's answer, this is a list of services and open sources that might be useful:

- [WP Package Editor](https://wordpress.recuweb.com/)

> WP2E is a service allowing developers to create and manage installation
> packages to deliver and maintain sets of interdependent themes and
> plugins.

- [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/)

> TGM Plugin Activation is a PHP library that allows you to easily
> require or recommend plugins for your WordPress themes (and plugins).

- [WPFavs](https://wpfavs.com/)

> It is a Free WordPress plugin manager and bulk installation tool

- [WordPress Packagist](https://wpackagist.org/)

> This site mirrors the WordPress plugin and theme directories as a
> Composer repository.

- [WP Plugin Dependencies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-dependencies/)

> This meta-plugin allows regular plugins to specify other plugins that
> they depend upon.

- [WP Dependency Installer](https://github.com/afragen/wp-dependency-installer)

> A lightweight class to add to WordPress plugins/themes to
> automatically install plugin dependencies.